# Move the Sharepoint WebApplications to another Tier 3 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I  have to  to move all the web applications to a SharePoint farm ,Please describe steps  to move all the contents from one server to another. If you have any third party tool /PowerShell snippet share it to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, think i've already found the solution with this:

http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Regards,
Gowtham

Answer (score 2):

If it's all about regular SharePoint farm, then the migration is relatively easy:

1. Make sure build versions are same
2. Recreate web application at destination farm (`New-SPWebApplication`)
3. Detach content databases from source farm (`Remove-SPContentDatabase`)
4. Attach content databases to newly created web application at destination farm (`New-SPContentDatabase`)

Repeat this for each web application. Then set all common services up, like Search, UPS.

If you have 3rd party applications what deployed custom assemblies, then it gets harder - you'll have to redeploy them all.

It's for the simplest case - I'm assuming your AD domain will be the same, and DBS is not going to change. **But** any complex service/features like Content Type Hubs, Managed Metadata Services, Word/Excel/Access services require additional separate planning. This can't be advised without knowing your exact AS-IS state.